# Is it possible to connect a PHPmyAdmin database using Angular and Postman?

Tags: php, angular, phpmyadmin

this is my first time using StackOverflow and I don't know how this works but I'll be quick and short. So, I'm in an internship and I'm learning Angular and I only know the basics. They told me to make a simple project so I can understand the basics of Angular by making a task manager and using as Database PHPmyAdmin and of course PHP language. I did the database and I'm using Postman to get the HTTP request as the company colleagues told me to use. I want to understand if it is possible to make the database connection to Angular and how.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a database administration tool, not a database. That is important to know. The database is probably MySQL or MariaDB. So you need to just find some database connection information and then read a tutorial on connecting Angular with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

No because there's no such thing as a "phpmyadmin database".

Phpmyadmin is a tool for interacting with a mysql/mariadb database management system which will contain one or more databases.

Meanwhile angular is a toolkit/framework/library for writing JavaScript code to run in a browser. Browsers communicate with servers using http. Mariadb and mysql don't speak http. You need to build something serverside to bridge the http to the DBMS. You appear to be using PHP serverside already for this but there are lots of other languages.

Comment: Do u reccomend any server that speaks http? Yes, I'm using PHP serverside because it was one of the languages that I have more experience since i'm in a school internship so we have to use what we learn.